# How to serialize QueryDict with list field?

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework, request, deserialization

Send url: https://...entities/?ids=[1, 2, 3]

```py
class EntityListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ids = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.IntegerField())

class EntityListView(BaseView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params = request.query_params # <QueryDict: {'ids': ['[1, 2, 3]']}>
        request_serializer = EntityListSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        request_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ...
```

Resonse json:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "ids": [
            "Обязательное поле."
        ]
    }
}
```

How to serialize it in right way?

Comment: tried https://...entities/?ids=1&ids=2 isn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class EntityListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ids = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.IntegerField())

class EntityListView(BaseView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params = request.query_params
        request_serializer = EntityListSerializer(data=query_params.dict())
        request_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ...
```

Comment: `query_params = request.query_params.dict() # {'ids': '[1, 2, 3]'}` Serializer error: Expected list, got str

Answer (score 0):

My solution: url like  https://...entities/?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3

```py
class EntityListView(BaseView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query['ids'] = [int(id) for ids in query.getlist('ids')]
        request_serializer = EntityListSerializer(data=query.dict())
        ...
```